# Protecting client side logic & data

Tags: javascript, security, webclient

I am coding a data intense web app. 
So that means I cant be possibly doing any computations on sever- computation after every event involves huge data too large to be sent to sever again & again.

So I have to do all execution & keep all data on clint side only. Currently I am using JS to do so. Is there a way by which I can protect my  js files & data so that no one has (atleast an easy) access to it ?

Is there some other way of putting (except JS) to put logic & data on client & conceal them ?

thanks,

Comment: Put some money in an envelope. Walk down the street and hand-over the envelope to a random person, and tell him not to open it. How sure are you of protecting your money?

Comment: lol...Incidentally today only I got first satisfactory response to one of my questions.

Comment: Use Encode.js : encodejs.devincity.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using javascript for the client side logic, perhaps you could use an applet which was compiled from obfuscated java source code.

Comment: Thats a nice suggestion. Are there easy ways of communicating data on fly between server & applets ?

Comment: Yes. The applet can make an HTTP call back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot protect javascript files.

--

I'm not aware of the specifics of your application, but there is almost certainly a way for the user to manipulate the data while it resides on your server.

You should open a new question with more details about your app.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your logic is concerned, you can use [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29#Web_Development) tools to make the code a bit hard to figure.  This in no way shape or form completely protects your code, but just another tactic to fight back.